# What's wrong in my login program?

Tags: c#

It should ask me for my password after I enter the correct username, but it didn't. What's wrong with it? Thanks.

```
bool username = false;
bool password = false;
bool adminpanel = false;
bool login = false;
string lastline = richTextBox1.Lines[richTextBox1.Lines.Length - 1]; //get last line of richtextbox

if (lastline == "login")
{
    login = true;
    richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "\nEnter your username\n";
}
lastline = richTextBox1.Lines[richTextBox1.Lines.Length - 1]; //get last line of richtextbox
if (login == true && lastline == "username")
{
    username = true;
    richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "\nEnter your password\n";
}
lastline = richTextBox1.Lines[richTextBox1.Lines.Length - 1]; //get last line of richtextbox
if (username == true && lastline == "12345678")
{
    password = true;
    adminpanel = true;
    richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "\nWelcome User!\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method adds a line "Enter your username" to the RichText Control and then it goes on to check if last line is Username immediately. Last line, at this point is "Enter your username" and hence, it doesn't ask for password.

At what stage are you entering the username because, the code which is shown above,doesn't provide you a timegap to update the control before moving on ?

Comment: I type login and click enter, it ask me to enter username, when I type username and click enter. Nothing shows up. It should ask me for password that time or tell me if the username is wrong. But it didn't tell me that. And I don't really understand your explanation yet. I'm kinda new to c# still learning so..yeah..thanks

Comment: Hi Jimmy, the reason is, your function has completed execution before you actually type in the user name.

Comment: You could call the above method in the KeyDown Event of the RichText Control. For example,
    private void richTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
{
// Your Code
}
}

Comment: As this method is kinda hard, I just make separate forms